# Video-related events tracking on iOS/HTML5

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ios5, html5-video

How would it be possible to track various parameters (such as Play/Pause/Stop/JumpToTime/Volume/others) with `<video>` tag on *iOS*? I would like to listen to those events and perform some application-specific actions.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#Media_Events

Comment: thank you. could you also provide some syntax examples?

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/HTML5VideoEventFlow/Listings/events_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010085-events_js-DontLinkElementID_5

Comment: which part of that web page gives the answer? It appears to be an index page